# Mechanism for polling asynchronous Data?

Tags: c#

I am newbie in c# thing so excuse me.I have a Console application project in which first i am sending some start command to my Arduino which will start rotating motor attached to it.This motor is attached to some Encoder on HMI and selecting some functionality (it's like volume button).When some functionality is achieved this information goes back to c# project at run time(not via Arduino but in loop). i need to wait for this feedback data after i send start command (at run time a variable value(functionality ID)  in the project will change i need to see that data )to be received and based on that data i need to send some further data.How can i achieve that ? Please Help

Comment: Could you post your codes and we'll tell you what is missing or what you are doing wrong.

Comment: If you're using .NET Core 3.0 or higher combined with C# 8, I'd recommend you take a look at [asynchronous streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/generate-consume-asynchronous-stream)